# nyc report fails with ENOENT when run through Cypress code-coverage plugin in CircleCI

Tags: code-coverage, cypress, circleci, nyc

I'm using the Cypress [code-coverage](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage) and [instrument-cra](https://github.com/cypress-io/instrument-cra) plugins. This works just fine when run locally on my own machine, but when run through CircleCI I get:

```
CypressError: cy.task('coverageReport') failed with the following error:
> Error: Command failed with ENOENT: nyc report --report-dir ./coverage --temp-dir /root/app/.nyc_output --reporter=lcov --reporter=clover --reporter=json
spawn nyc ENOENT
```

It's not clear which file it complains about. I've verified that /root/app/.nyc_output exists and contains coverage data.

I've enabled debug logging in Cypress and got:

```
code-coverage parsed sent coverage +0ms
code-coverage created folder /root/app/.nyc_output for output coverage +1ms
code-coverage wrote coverage file /root/app/.nyc_output/out.json +17ms
cypress:server:plugins:child execute plugin event: task ({ eventId: 2, invocationId: 'inv11' }) +100ms
code-coverage saving coverage report using command: "nyc report --report-dir ./coverage --temp-dir /root/app/.nyc_output --reporter=lcov --reporter=clover --reporter=json" +68ms
code-coverage current working directory is /root/app +0ms
```

The full run is available at https://circleci.com/gh/magjac/graphviz-visual-editor/114

I've followed [this guide](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/09/05/cypress-code-coverage-for-create-react-app-v3/) to set things up.

This is my CircleCI config.yaml (with lots of horrible debug and a workaround):

```
# Javascript Node CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  integration-test:
    docker:
      - image: cypress/base:8
        environment:
          ## this enables colors in the output
          TERM: xterm
    working_directory: ~/app
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}
            - v1-deps
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          no_output_timeout: 30m
          command: npm ci

      - save_cache:
          key: v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          # cache NPM modules and the folder with the Cypress binary
          paths:
            - ~/.npm
            - ~/.cache
      - run: ls -la
      - run: ls -la ./node_modules/.bin
      - run: ls -la .nyc_output/out.json || true
      - run: mkdir -p ./coverage
      - run: ls -la -R coverage || true
      - run: make
# This is the line that fails, but we ignore it and let the workaround below do its job
      - run: npm run start:coverage & $(npm bin)/wait-on http://localhost:3000/ && env CYPRESS_DEBUG="code-coverage" DEBUG="code-coverage" $(npm bin)/cypress run --record --key a12725d3-851c-4e67-b432-079b4fb1a875 --spec cypress/integration/rendering.spec.js || true
      - run: find . -name coverage || true
      - run: ls -la -R coverage || true
      - run: ls -la
      - run: ls -la .nyc_output/out.json || true
# Workaround: Run nyc report stand-alone
      - run: ./node_modules/.bin/nyc report --report-dir ./coverage --temp-dir /root/app/.nyc_output --reporter=lcov --reporter=clover --reporter=json
      - run: find . -name .nyc_output || true
      - run: find . -name coverage || true
      - run: ls -la .nyc_output/out.json || true
      - run: ls -la -R coverage || true
      - run: yarn run codecov
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-integration-test:
    jobs:
      - integration-test
```

**EDIT:** It's the nyc command that is not found. Adding `env PATH="$PATH:./node_modules/.bin" before Cypress invocation solves the problem. Do I really have to use this or is there a better way?

**EDIT 2:** A better workaround is to use `npx cypress run` which sets the path to node_modules/.bin automatically. Perhaps this is the real solution?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$(npm bin)/cypress run` with `npx cypress run` according to my **EDIT 2** in the question above.

I cannot tell if this is actually the correct solution or if it's a workaround for something.

Comment: I think it's not the solution, i've a similar problem using docker container and i use npx.